# Data frame loop stops

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to loop through a data frame with with conditional statements.

I have attempted splitting up the loop and they all work individually; however, when combined, the loop stops after 1 iteration.

```
i=0 
stock = 100
cash = 0

for index, row in df2.iterrows(): 
    if df2.iloc[i][3] > df2.iloc[i+1][3]:          
        if stock == 0:                             #future stock is cheaper, but no stock to sell
           continue 
        else:
            cash = cash + df2.iloc[i][3] * stock   #future stock is cheaper, so sell
            stock = 0 
    else:                                          #future stock is more expensive, so buy 
        stock = round((cash/df2.iloc[i][3])-0.5) 
       cash = round((cash - stock*df2.iloc[i][3])-0.5)
    i+=1
i
```

printing i gives only 1 when it should give a list of numbers (i.e. the loop stopped after one iteration)

Comment: I suppose you print `i` in the last line (I recommend using `print()`). But `i` is not in the loop, so it will only print at the end of the loop, when it has finished.

Comment: DGB your ```i``` is a scalar, it will always have value, it is not a list in your design

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: what index and row are for?

Answer (score 0):

Because your print i outside of your `for` loop you will not get a list of numbers but only the last value of `i`

Also maybe it's a copy/paste error but you have an indent before `stock = round((cash/df2.iloc[i][3])-0.5)` to much.

Can you give an example on what is inside your dataframe ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using a loop over `df2` rows, but you are not using your `index` and `row` anywhere in the loop.
If you are trying to loop over every row in your `df2` then I would suggest:

```
i=0 
stock = 100
cash = 0

for i in range(df2.shape[0]-1): # iterate over all rows except last iloc[i+1] is the last
    if df2.iloc[i][3] > df2.iloc[i+1][3]:          
        if stock == 0:                             #future stock is cheaper, but   no stock to sell
           continue 
        else:
            cash = cash + df2.iloc[i][3] * stock   #future stock is cheaper, so sell 
            stock = 0 
    else:                                          #future stock is more expensive, so buy 
        stock = round((cash/df2.iloc[i][3])-0.5) 
        cash = round((cash - stock*df2.iloc[i][3])-0.5)
print(i)
```